MAX31865 power supply and filtering
I am designing a RTD circuit for PT1000 using the MAX31865 IC, and by reading the datasheet, I am a bit confused/in doubt.
There is no info in the datasheet about using separate analog/digital power supplies, so I am thinking it should be ok to use a separate 3.3V LDO for both. It only states that both Vdd and DVdd should be connected to a 3.3V power supply.
Also there is no info related to RTD input filtering (differential and/or common mode), so I am guessing this is built in internally. This is not shown in the functional diagram though (only a sinc filter is described).
My circuit is as shown below, and I am wondering if it is sufficient. I will be doing EMC tests soon, so I want it to be as EMI/EMC secure as possible. Would appreciate input on the circuit and also feedback on the power supply and filtering questions. If anyone has used this IC before I would appreciate any other insights as well.


Is the RTD going to be within a few cm of the chip or are you trying to build an industrial-hardened input circuit?

3-5m RTD cable, and I am trying to build an industrial-hardened input circuit.
